# How to create bitmap image and show data in it from DB

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, bitmapimage

Hello I'm beginner and i want t create image like this:  [one line diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYgO.png)

values of boxes are coming from database and changing time by time.

any guidance for creating and filling data on it please.

Comment: So the only data in boxes will change, not the diagram itself?

Comment: yes the data will only change not the image

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare a template bitmap in some image editor, with empty boxes (MS paint, Paint.Net or any other). Then, draw text above the boxes. Something like this:

```
    Bitmap templateBmp = Bitmap.FromFile("your_template_bitmap.bmp");
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(templateBmp))
    {
       g.DrawString("Hello world", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
    }

    templateBmp.Save("C:\\temp\\MyNewBmp.bmp");
```

Comment: bro i'm beginner and dont know any about image creation. any reference or your any done example can help me